# Logout with Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am trying to do a user auth, and I am in the part of the logout now

```
      <button ng-click="logOut(user)">
        GOING OUT
      </button>
```

here is how they sign in

```
  $scope.signIn = function (user) {
    $scope.signInErrorShow = false;
    if (user && user.email && user.pwdForLogin) {
      auth.$authWithPassword({
        email: user.email,
        password: user.pwdForLogin
      }).then(function (authData) {
        console.log("Logged in as:" + authData.password.email);
        ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).once('value', function (snapshot) {
          var val = snapshot.val();
          $scope.$apply(function () {
            $rootScope.displayName = val;
          });
        });
        $scope.userLogin = true;
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $scope.closeModal();
        $rootScope.$broadcast('');
      }).catch(function (error) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
      });
    } else
    $scope.signInErrorShow = true;
  };
```

and I am trying to call logOut

```
  $scope.logOut = function(user) {
    ref.unauth();
  };
```

once I call log out, I don't see any post or get in the Network section of the browser.

In the Firebase Docs, all they say about log out is this

> Logging Users Out
>
> Calling unauth() invalidates the user's token and logs them out of your application:
>
> Copy
> ref.unauth();
> If you had previously used the onAuth() method to listen for authentication state, your callback would now be invoked with null for authData.

so what should I do here ?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is: once you call `unauth()` you don't see any new data; that sounds like expected behavior to me. Were you expecting the `onAuth()` callback? The code you show in the question doesn't register an `onAuth()` callback, so that won't be called. See: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/onauth.html

Comment: Ok, so it is ok what I am doing ? that's all I need to know. If a user logs in, I can see a Get in Network, but once the user logs out, I don't see anything going on in the Network, so I want to know how I can realize if the user was log out of the app ? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: If you want to be sure, register an `onAuth` handler.

Comment: Also see Jacob's last comment here: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/601#issuecomment-93835141

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-angular/gQzyZ5VgwXU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning logout not showing any network activity: on login firebase probably gives you an access token (kept by the firebase client script) when you login.

When after login your application accesses firebase it adds this token to the header of your requests (authorization header?).

When you logoff the firebase client script simply erases the token. This way the firebase backend doesn't have to keep session state on their (distributed) servers. They only have to check the validity of the token sent in each request.

Comment: yes, after some research I realize it. thank you so much my friend.