# New Firebase methods for User Auth

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase

The reason why I am starting with this topic, is because in every search for something related to Firebase and User Auth all you see goes to SIMPLE LOGIN which is **deprecated** already. So I want to clear some doubts and I would like to receive feedback with the best ways to implement the Firebase functions/methods.

Would be better if we provide examples with the JS and HTML parts. I am going to start with some code of an app I am developing

first the creation of new users, login and logout

```
//CREATE USER
<form name="sign-up">

      <input type="text" ng-model="user.name">

      <input type="email" ng-model="user.email">

      <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">

      <input type="password" ng-model="user.confirm">

      <button ng-click="createUser(user)">
       Create Account
      </button>

    <label ng-if="signUpErrorShow">
      <span>{{signUpErrorMsg}}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>

//LOGIN USER
<form name="login">
      <input type="text" ng-model="user.email">

      <input type="password" ng-model="user.pwdForLogin">

      <button ng-click="signIn(user)">
        LOGIN
      </button>

      <button ng-click="logOut(user)">
        Logout
      </button>

    <label class="item item-text-wrap text-center" ng-if="signInErrorShow">
      <span>{{signInErrorMsg}}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

that is the HTML for the creating part and the login, here I have a questions, beside the email and the password, I added an input with user.name where the user enter his name, once the logs in, what can I do to display his name using Angular interpolation ?

here is the service

```
angular.module('urbanet.app.services', [])
// create a custom Auth factory to handle $firebaseAuth
.factory("Auth", function ($firebaseAuth, $rootScope) {
  var ref = new Firebase('https://urbanetapp.firebaseio.com/');
  return $firebaseAuth(ref);
});
```

is there something more I need to add there ?

now the controller:

```
angular.module('urbanet.app.controllers', [])

.controller("LoginCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicLoading, $ionicModal,
                                  $timeout, $firebaseAuth, $state, $ionicPopup) {

  var ref = new Firebase('https://urbanetapp.firebaseio.com/'),
      auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

  $scope.signUpErrorShow = false;
  $scope.signInErrorShow = false;

  //CREATING USER
  $scope.createUser = function(user) {
    $scope.validationError = false;
    if (user && user.email && user.name ) {
      if (user.password === user.confirm ) {

        auth.$createUser({
          email: user.email,
          password: user.password
        }).then(function (userData) {
          ref.child("users").child(userData.uid).set({
            email: user.email,
            displayName: user.name
          });
        }).catch(function (error) {
          alert("Error: " + error);
          $ionicLoading.hide();
        });
        $ionicPopup.show({
          template: 'Succesfully created',
          scope: $scope,
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Accept',
              onTap: function() {
                $state.transitionTo('tabs.news');
              }
            }
          ]
        });

      }else {
        $scope.signUpErrorMsg = "Error confirming pass";
      }
    }else {
      $scope.signUpErrorMsg = "Required field";
    }
  };

  //LOGIN USER
  $scope.signIn = function (user) {
    $scope.signInErrorShow = false;
    if (user && user.email && user.pwdForLogin) {
      auth.$authWithPassword({
        email: user.email,
        password: user.pwdForLogin
      }).then(function (authData) {
        ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).once('value', function (snapshot) {
          var val = snapshot.val();
          $scope.$apply(function () {
            $rootScope.displayName = val;
          });
        });
      }).catch(function (error) {
        $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'Error entering',
          template: "Auth failed " + error.message
        });
      });
    } else
    $scope.signInErrorShow = true;
    $scope.signInErrorMsg = 'E-mail & pass required'
  };

  // LOG OUT USER
  $scope.logOut = function() {
    ref.unauth();
  };    
});
```

now, is there something wrong with my code ? something weird here is that once I create the user I see data returned in the Network part of the browser, the same once I do login, but once I do logout I don't see anything going on, is that the proper behavior ?

Also, here is where I need the most of your help, I need to implement a method to reset a password. [Here are the docs for that](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html#section-reset-email), how that functionality works ? do I need first to set the changing password method ? or how ?

The help of all of you here is very important for the rest of the people, not only me, as I mentioned above, most of the examples by users in the web, are related to the old firebase method of Authentication.

Comment: What did you try to reset the password? Because that documentation reference you have is pretty explicit (and up to date): `ref.resetPassword({ email: "whatever@yourprovider.com" })`

Answer (score 1):

The 'auth' object returned from the factory is a firebase object. Better design would be to encapsulate this functionality in your own service. Changes in the firebase api then reflect only on your service, and not on all places in your application that use authentication.

```
angular.module('urbanet.app.services', [])
// create a custom Auth factory to handle $firebaseAuth
.factory("AuthService", function ($firebaseAuth, $rootScope) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://urbanetapp.firebaseio.com/");
  var firebaseAuth = $firebaseAuth(ref);


  // now create the interface between firebase and your application
  var authService = {};

  authService.logon = function(credentials){
    ... probably reference firebaseAuth object somewhere here
  }
  authService.logoff = function(){
    ... probably reference firebaseAuth object somewhere here
  }
  authservice.createUser = function(credentials){
    ... probably reference firebaseAuth object somewhere here
  }
  authService.resetPassword = function(...){
    ... probably reference firebaseAuth object somewhere here
  }       
  return authService;
});
```

In your controllers you just need to call the methods on authService, and not some backend specific code that changes all the time.

```
angular.module('urbanet.app.controllers', [])

.controller("LoginCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicLoading, $ionicModal,
             $timeout, AuthService, $state, $ionicPopup) {

    ...
    AuthService.createUser(...)
      .then(function(response){
        ...
    })
    ...
})
```

This also makes it easy to swap firebase for another auth provider if you choose so.

Concerning logout not showing any network activity: on login firebase probably gives you an access token (kept by the firebase client script) when you login. When after login your application accesses firebase it adds this token to the header of your request (authorization header?). When you logoff the firebase client script simply erases the token. 
This way the firebase backend doesn't have to keep session state on their (distributed) servers. They only have to check the validity of the token sent in each request.

Sorry to be of no assistance with the password reset question. I would have to look that up...

Comment: For some extra credits, can you copy/paste your remark about logout here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885273/logout-with-firebase? I'll upvote. :-)